# Send mail with CDO through Google Apps gives transport error: CDO.Message.1 error '80040213'

Tags: asp-classic, google-apps, cdo.message

I'm trying to send an contact enquiry email from a legacy classic asp script using a Google Apps account as the SMTP server. The code I have to test this is as follows:

```
Dim ObjSendMail
Set ObjSendMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 

'This section provides the configuration information for the remote SMTP server.
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network).
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") ="mail.thedomain.com"
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465 ' or 587
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60

' Google apps mail servers require outgoing authentication. Use a valid email address and password registered with Google Apps.
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 'basic (clear-text) authentication
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") ="info@thedomain.com" 'your Google apps mailbox address
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") ="password" 'Google apps password for that mailbox

ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Update

ObjSendMail.To = "me@mydomain.net"
ObjSendMail.Subject = "this is the subject"
ObjSendMail.From = "info@thedomain.com"

' we are sending a text email.. simply switch the comments around to send an html email instead
'ObjSendMail.HTMLBody = "this is the body"
ObjSendMail.TextBody = "this is the body"

ObjSendMail.Send
Set ObjSendMail = Nothing
```

I've tried both port numbers 465 and 587.  I've tried mail.thedomain.com and smtp.thedomain.com and mail.gmail.com and smtp.gmail.com as the SMTP server, but nothing works.  I've logged into the Google Apps account with the email address and password in the script, so those details are definitely correct.

All I can get though is the following error:

```
CDO.Message.1 error '80040213'

The transport failed to connect to the server.

/_test-email.asp, line 46
```

(line 46 is where it says ObjSendMail.Send)

Can anyone see what might be wrong?

Thanks folks!

Comment: @Calon stop editing all the questions in the same way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried with **Gmail** smtp server and a little changes to your code and it worked like a charm.

Just modify these 3 parameters and you are good to go.

```
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") ="smtp.gmail.com"
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `smtpusessl` to `1` (true) (I see you have it set to `false`)

Comment: Thanks - I forgot to mention I've tried both true and false (and 1 and 0) for that field too, but still get the same error. Could it be something to do with the local host (some kind of firewall problem or the 'mail.thedomain.com' address is routing locally hence not connecting??) I've no idea when it comes to server admin and the hosting company aren't offering much help either :(

Comment: I just tested it with my Google Apps account, `smtpserver = "smtp.gmail.com", smtpserverport = 465, smtpusessl = 1` and it worked perfectly. if it's still not working it would suggest a firewall issue on your end?