# emails not arriving using cdo and microsoft smtp server

Tags: asp-classic, smtp

i am trying to send an email using asp classic. using the code below, i get no errors. however the emails do not arrive at all. all messages are directly sent to my BadMail folder. any ideas as to why this is happening?

```
<%
Set ObjSendMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverpickupdirectory") = "d:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup"
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Update

ObjSendMail.From = "myemail@domain.com"
ObjSendMail.To = "targetemail@anotherdomain.com"

ObjSendMail.Subject = "TEST EMAIL"

ObjSendMail.TextBody="This is a message."

ObjSendMail.Send
set ObjSendMail=nothing
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, not a lot of detail, but here's my experience.
Certain smtp servers require a different port number. For instance, gmail requires port 465.
Here's some more info on sending via gmail: [Send mail with CDO through Google Apps gives transport error: CDO.Message.1 error '80040213'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669644/send-mail-with-cdo-through-google-apps-gives-transport-error-cdo-message-1-erro)

If you're using another smtp server, then try googling the key words cdo, asp, and whatever your server is.

Hope this helps. Good luck.