# Sending mail using classic ASP?

Tags: email, asp-classic, smtp

I am trying to send mail using classic ASP, but my page contain some error that's why when 
upload the page it shows the error that :

> 500 Internal Server Error

This is the code i am using;

```vbs
<%
Dim smtpserver,youremail,yourpassword,ContactUs_Name,ContactUs_Tel,ContactUs_Email
Dim ContactUs_Subject,ContactUs_Body,Action,IsError

smtpserver = "smtp.gmail.com"
youremail = "xxxxx.yyyyyy@gmail.com"
yourpassword = "password" 

Dim ObjSendMail
Set ObjSendMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 587 
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1 'Use SSL for the connection
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 'basic (clear-text) authentication
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "aaaaa.bbbbbb@gmail.com"
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "password"
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
ObjSendMail.To = "aaaaa.bbbbbb@gmail.com"
ObjSendMail.CC = "cccccc.dddddd@sunarctechnologies.com"
ObjSendMail.Subject = "Subject"
ObjSendMail.From = "xxxxx.yyyyyy@gmail.com"
ObjSendMail.HTMLBody = "<p>hello</p>"
ObjSendMail.Send
Set ObjSendMail = Nothing 
%>
```

I don't have any idea of classic asp this is just copy paste code from some other source.

Comment: are these lines containing `http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/...` still correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct but I'd check wheter gmail only accepts SSL connections on port 465. I believe port 567 is for TLS connections. Alternatively just try port 25.

[This question is similar to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669644/send-mail-with-cdo-through-google-apps-gives-transport-error-cdo-message-1-erro).

You also really need to be able to see the detailed error messages your application is reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to IIS, the first thing I recommend is to activate server side debugging and send errors to browser on in IIS. An error 500 can mean anything form a missing end if to the object not being found. Having a proper error message to work with will help narrow down the source of the problem.